# Select tag is inserting duplicate rows in sql

Tags: jquery, ajax

If click function is clicked for first time there are no duplicate rows

When it is clicked for second time 2 rows get inserted

for third time 3 rows and so on..

html

```
<select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
   <option value="pick">Select</option>                                             
   <option name="id" id="id" value="1">Name1</option>
   <option name="id2" id="id2" value="2">Name2</option>     
</select>
```

jquery..

```
$('#select').on('change', function (j){
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $('#select').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "new.php",
      data: '{"to":"'+selectedValue+'"}',
      success: function(r){

    }
  });
 });
});
```

Why is this happening..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should unbind any existing event first

```
$("#btn").off().click(function(){
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the button click handler inside the change handler. So you end up adding an extra handler every time.
You can get rid of the select change handler.

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $('#select').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "new.php",
      data: '{"to":"'+selectedValue+'"}',
      success: function(r){

    }
  });
 });
```

This much is sufficient.